# GORM queries specific rows of data and obtains the sum of its field score values。

Tags: mysql, go, grails-orm

The following statement is used：

```
id []int64

type Score struct {
    Score int `gorm:"score"`
}
func GetScoreByID(score *Score, id []int64) error {
    db.Table("question_bank").Select("sum(score) as score").Where("id IN ?", id).Scan(&score).Error
}
```

Report the following error：

```
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?)' at line 1
```

How can I write to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Try read [gorm offical docs](https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#Count)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get sum of salary column from table GORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53757955/how-to-get-sum-of-salary-column-from-table-gorm)

Answer (score 0):

Just change function parameter `score *Score` to `score *int64` and as score is pointer so no need to put `&` before score in `Scan`.

```
func GetScoreByID(score *int64, id []int64) error {
    return db.Table("question_bank").
      Select("sum(score)").
      Where("id IN ?", id).
      Scan(score).Error
}
```