# Error while sending request in Go with gin and gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I started Go very recently and decided to create a simple CRUD back-end using `gorm` and `gin`.I have implemented the following function to retrieve a query result.

I can't get some of the endpoints to work.

```golang
func GetCurrentStock(c *gin.Context) {
    result := initializers.DB.Table("dev.inventory_live").Debug().Select("sum(qtynos)").Where("NOT is_cut AND (remarks IS NULL OR remarks = '')")

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "result": result,
    })
}
```

When I send a request to the end point, I keep getting this error

```
Error #01: json: unsupported type: func() time.Time
```

Is there something I am missing? I haven't been able to find a solution

Comment: `result` is of type `*gorm.DB` which embeds `*gorm.Config` which has a field [`NowFunc func() time.Time`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#Config.NowFunc). Passing `result` to `c.JSON` will attempt to marshal it as JSON. __Functions cannot be marshaled into JSON__, hence the error. Neither are you supposed to be marshaling `*gorm.DB`. In other words, `result` is not what you think it is. Read the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm), read the official tutorials from [gorm.io](https://gorm.io/docs/).

Answer (score 1):

Using the input @mkopriva gave and another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53757955/how-to-get-sum-of-salary-column-from-table-gorm) I found, I realised I was incorrectly retrieving the result. The right way is:

```
func GetCurrentStock(c *gin.Context) {
    var result int
    initializers.DB.Table("dev.inventory_live").Select(fmt.Sprintf("sum(%v)", dim)).Where("NOT is_cut AND (remarks IS NULL OR remarks = '')").Scan(&result)

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "result": result,
    })
}
```